# Redis Syntax error with arabic characters

Tags: bash, scala, encoding, redis

In Redis version 3.2.3 I am getting an error when trying to set:

```
    set test اتلات بين حماس  ح
    (error) ERR syntax error
```

I will be accessing Redis from Scala and from bash. So a common encoding is needed. But the main problem is that it fails by itself in a simple Redis command in the cli.

PS: tested using `redis-cli --raw` did not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add quotes because you have spaces in your string, it is not related to the character encoding:

```
> set test "اتلات بين حماس ح"
OK
> get test
"اتلات بين حماس ح"
```